# ControlTemplate Storyboard color animation problem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, animation

I have a problem with color animation. This is my source:

```xml
 <Window.Resources>
    <hedit:BrushToColorConverter x:Key="BrushToColorConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="buttonAnimIn">
                            <!-- Problem line -->
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bntBack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Converter={StaticResource BrushToColorConverter}}" />
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="buttonAnimOut">
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bntBack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Blue" />
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="buttonAnimForegroundIn">
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="btnFore" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Blue" />
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="buttonAnimForegroundOut">
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="btnFore" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Red" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Border Name="border" 
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Padding="4,2" 
                        BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
                        CornerRadius="3">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" x:Name="bntBack" />
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                            <ContentControl.Foreground>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" x:Name="btnFore" />
                            </ContentControl.Foreground>
                        </ContentControl >
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource buttonAnimIn}" />
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource buttonAnimForegroundIn}" />
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseLeave">
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource buttonAnimOut}" />
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource buttonAnimForegroundOut}" />
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The problem is:

Cannot convert the value in attribute 'Style' to object of type 'System.Windows.Style'. Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' in markup file 'HLSLEditor;component/mainwindow.xaml' Line 223 Position 25.

When using fixed colors it worked, but it cannot work with the Foreground color of the parent...

How do I do an animation to the foreground or background color?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the point of Storyboards is to group animations, so you normally would only have an `InStoryboard` and `OutStoryboard`, where each contains two animations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot freeze Bindings, you probably can get around this issue by declaring a color as a resource and then bind your Control's Background to it while using StaticResource in the animation.

e.g.

```xml
<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource Background}"/>
</Window.Background>
<Window.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="Background">Green</Color>
</Window.Resources>
```

```xml
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                Duration="0:0:1"
                To="{StaticResource Background}"/>
```

Alternative using a resource class:

```
public static class MyColors
{
    public static Color MyHighlightColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 88, 0);
}
```

```xml
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                Duration="0:0:1"
                To="{x:Static local:MyColors.MyHighlightColor}"/>
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion H.B. however the problem is that all my colors are in a resource file, we have skinning in the app. is there a way to go over this that does not include static colors declared in the xaml file?

Comment: What kind of resource file? If it declares the colors as static public fields you can use `{x:Static namespace:Class.Field}` instead of using static resources. ([x:Static Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx))

Comment: to clarify: a dynamic resource file: Background and foreground colors of the main controls are binded by a DynamicResource binding. All the inner elements in control template are bound to the control colors that contain them... when i need to change the skin i change the resource dictionary, that is why i need the DynamicResource

Comment: Unfortunately that might be impossible, at the very least i cannot think of a way to do that, sorry...

Answer (score 2):

I think that understanding the error might give you a way of fixing the problem.

Animation requires the use of threads besides the UI thread.  So storyboards have to be freezable, which means that all the animations in the storyboard must be freezable, and everything those animations use must also be freezable.

Bindings aren't freezable - pretty much by definition, as they are a mechanism whereby a dependency property can be changed.  You can't use a dynamic binding in a color animation - there's the possibility that the property could change while the animation was running.  The same thing happens whether you're binding to an object or you're using `DynamicResource`.

The thing is, this is protecting you from something that you don't really want anyway.  You don't really want the colors to change while the animation is running.  That's not what you're trying to accomplish.  You want the color resources that the animation is using to change if the user selects a different skin.

So instead of binding storyboards to skinnable resources, add the storyboards to the dictionary of resources that get set when the skin changes (using static bindings to set the colors), and use dynamic binding in your event triggers.  That should work.

Comment: Thanks for your view, that's unfortunately what i thought after some research, now with your confirmation. XAML out, .cs in seems the only solution :/

Comment: I think what I suggested just involves moving XAML, not replacing it with code.  I don't know enough about your application to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

When I came across this problem I worked around it by modifying my style to contain two identical elements on top of each other - one for the 'normal' state and one for the 'pressed' state. The 'pressed' one had its `Opacity` set to 0 by default and the other one had an `Opacity` of 1. My animation changed the opacities from 0 to 1 and vice versa.

This approach avoided actually animating the `Color` property but produced the same effect whilst keeping everything in XAML. As the colours were set in the style definition rather than the animation they could be bound as required. This will probably not be suitable for all situations but for my fairly simple style it was a very quick way to achieve the desired effect.