# Style to choose suitable foreground according to background color

Tags: wpf, styles, background-color, foreground

I have a WPF application which ships with a set of default styles for Label, TextBox etc. defined by item types (no explicit keys defined).

Within the application there are two main containers used, one with dark background and one with light background, such that sometimes it's right to use black as the foreground color for a Label and sometimes its dramatically wrong. On the other hand, editors are always styled rather traditionally with light background and dark foreground, so I cannot just set the foreground for all child elements to the inverse.

Is there an elegant way to make my labels (and maybe TextBlocks as well) to decide about their foreground color dependent on 'their' background? I only want to switch between two colors, thus no auto-contrast-maximization needed, only some threshold to avoid white font on white ground.

I also don't want to define two sets of default styles, I strongly search for some way to make my single Label-Default-Style be appropriate for both background variants.

Is it possible (and feasible without too much performance hit) to add a trigger/binding to the style, which evaluates the current background color?

Alternatively, I would be interested in best practices how to cleanly set background-colors for certain FrameworkElements, especially containers/panels, without running into the problems described above.

Here is what I tried (simplified of course):

```
  <UniformGrid>
  <UniformGrid.Resources>
  <!-- SimpleStyles: Label -->
     <Style x:Key="{x:Type Label}" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                 <Border>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                 </Border>
                 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Background" Value="Black">
                       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                    </Trigger>
                 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
     </Style>
  </UniformGrid.Resources>
  <Label x:Name="bgSetExplicitly" Background="Black">abc
  </Label>
  <Border Background="Black">
     <Label x:Name="bgInheritedFromParent" >abc
     </Label>
  </Border>
  <Label>abc
  </Label>
  <Label>abc
  </Label>
```

You can see that the label's background is chosen nicely, if the Label has an explicit background set (x:Name=bgSetExplicitly), but if the background is 'inherited' from the parent in the VisualTree (x:Name="bgInheritedFromParent"), it's not.
I would love to have that working that the style can evaluate the "effective background" (no matter where it comes from) and choose an appropriate foreeground-brush for this background.

Comment: I finally accepted Robert's suggestion:
Each container who sets a custom background must also set a suitable foreground. All Controls (Label, TextBox etc.) will have to respect these settings, s.th. a TextBox will look nice no matter in which container it will be placed.

Originally, I was trying to find a solution that would even work if some styles in the app are not following that rule, mainly for robustness because we can't runtime-test all dialogs after each change in one of the basic styles.
But that turned out to be more difficult than I had originally thought so I gave it up for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question seems to imply a deeper issue.  I would guess that you haven't consolidated the management of foreground colors, and so you have an application that has code or styles that set foreground colors all over the place.  And now you're dealing with one of the implications of that.

I'd face the deeper issue and fix that. I don't really understand why you're resistant to the idea of creating default styles, but assuming for the moment that you have a good reason not to do this (other than "I should have created default styles at some point, but now that I haven't and my application has gotten big, it's just too hard," in which case, I have a different suggestion), how about creating global resources?

Create objects in the application's resource dictionary for the controls' foreground and background colors, and fix the XAML so that instead of referencing brushes directly, it uses the `DynamicResource` markup extension to get them from the resource dictionary.  In code, instead of setting the `Foreground` property on the controls to a brush directly, use `GetResource` to get the brush.  And set the background the same way.

Once you've done this, if you want to change foreground/background colors globally in your application, you just change the resources.

This is basically how you start making a WPF application skinnable, which seems to be the road you're going down.

Comment: i know it's closed but could you please look my question and have a comment? I used the dynamic resources and had a problem with that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667987/wpf-controltemplate-storyboard-color-animation-problem

Comment: I'm not against default styles, I already use them. It's just that I want to have exactly one default style per control-type, wherever this is possible. This is exactly because I want to define all the styling in some central theme and not spread across the application.

Comment: i.e.: My single default style does not fit all situations, because the background color can be light here or dark there, and I don't want to set styles for individual controls all over the application. So I will need to find a way to make the default style smart enough to adapt to its environment.

Comment: How can it be that you can't set the foreground and background color at the same time whenever you set one of them?

Comment: Yes, I think this is that "Best Practice" I was searching for. Background and Foreground should always be set pairwise. 
For my app (not the sample posted), we will have to rework some styles to make sure they all respect this guideline and consume the foreground and background correctly. Will be a little bit painful, but I feel it's the right way to go.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do is bind the foreground color of your TextBoxes, etc. to the background of their containing element, and use a value converter to make the change.  This is especially easy if you are only ever using two colors.

As an example....

```
  public class ColorSwapper : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      if (value == null) { return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue; }

      Color srcColor = (value as SolidColorBrush).Color;
      if (srcColor == Colors.Black)
      {
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
      }
      else
      {
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
      }
    }
...
```

And some example XAML....

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Name="RightGrid" Background="White">
  <TextBlock Text="Hello Nurse!" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=RightGrid, Path=Background, Converter={StaticResource ColorSwapper}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Of course you will probably want to make some tweaks and cleanup according to your specific needs, but that will do it.

Comment: Surely this works, but this will make me add this extra binding to each single TextBlock or label all over my application, that will be some hundreds of them. Since in your example you are binding to a named element, the Binding will have to be a different one for each TextBlock, depending on its surrounding, so it won't work in a global Style.

Comment: Then just have the converter walk up the visual tree and determine the background color to convert from there.  Anyway, I do mention that you will have to tweak it according to your specific needs...

Comment: I thought the "value" in the value converter is not in the visual tree

Comment: It can be, depending on what you bind to.  You can also use a 'RelativeSource' binding to locate the desired ancestor that has the value you are looking for.  There are many many ways to skin this cat.

Comment: I will give it a try to get the "next available background-color", maybe I do this in my central style without touching all those single controls.

Comment: @Simon The big problem that you are going to run into is that it is very difficult to create a 'one size fits all' solution to your problem.  Sometimes the background color that you care about may not be immediately available, or unset, and so on.  At the end of the day you are talking about a system that needs a lot of information to provide your desired features.

Comment: added my try to the question for clarification.

Comment: You're definitely right, hitting them all with one shot won't be easy. But it would be a great help establishing a solid standard all over the application, and I strongly believe it's doable using some binding or trigger technique, which should be robust against all those 'not yet set'-problems.

Comment: I tried a Binding within the style using ColorSwapper-Converter and added some code to walk up the visual tree until it reaches some ancestor with Background set, but this way it won't work. 
I would probably have to walk down from the parent container, but I don't want to go that way to avoid overcomplexity.

Comment: I guess that's just the ting though.  The scenario that you are describing is somewhat complex, and depends on many factors.  I don't think that there is a *simple* solution in this case.  At the end of the day, it may just be easiest to forget the style and set all of the bindings in code.  Anyway, you have already accepted an (vague) answer so why bother discussing it anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible approach.  If your application only has ALL dark/light backgrounds and their compliments, you can try an approach like this, using the 'ColorSwapper' that I mentioned in my other answer.

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:ColorSwapper x:Key="swapper"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackBrush" Color="Black"/>
    <!--<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackBrush" Color="White"/>-->

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource BackBrush}, Converter={StaticResource swapper}}"/>
    </Style>

  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid Background="{StaticResource BackBrush}">
    <TextBlock FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold">ABC</TextBlock>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now whenever you change the color value of 'BackBrush', all of the related foreground colors will automatically update.  Based on your discussions, I think that this will also meet your style requirements.  At any rate, you will likely have to make small mods to ensure that this approach will fit your exact scenario.

Comment: yeah, that's closer, shifting the extra-definitions to the window (or other container). 
But I'm looking for a solution where the TextBlock-Style does it all alone, with no further requirements for the window or container.
Consider a window with many groupboxes, where the groupboxes have alternating background-colors, I want to use the same set of default styles for all those groupboxes.
I also want to use the same styles, if the groupboxes are no groupboxes but simple borders with varying backgrounds.
Sorry, it's quite lengthy to explain my motivation entirely.

Comment: Further reason why I would like to put all the functionality into the default styles of label/textblock etc: I have other elements which do not change their colors depending on the backgrounds, e.g. a TextBox brings its own solid black border with white background and black foreground, which works on both dark and light background.

Comment: OK, well I've given you two reasonable solutions.  Basically you want to make a style that is going to read your mind and that just isn't going to happen.  For the type of complex functionality that you are talking about, you are going to have to combine techniques, and probably do some codebehind.  Meanwhile, if you want more help with your problem, you are going to have to hire me on as a consultant.  Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, right. Thanks for all your efforts already, I will update this post if I finally get my mind-reading god-style - or if I decide to choose some other way. Unfortunately, I got no budget for consultants right now.