# Bind label Foreground to a variable

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpf-controls

I have a `User Interface` and I am changing the `background` property of the main grid. Now some give a very pleasent look but for some there is difficulty reading the text as displayed. However, a problem arises when I have approximately 20 labels around there now, and making them change and assign them color each time is making my code look ugly. I know there must be a more elegant design.

I tried to bind labels to a color but that does not work. here is code

XAML:

```
<Label Foreground="{Binding defColor}" Content="Settings" Height="44" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,53,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="26" />
```

Code behind:

```
  SolidColorBrush defColor = new SolidColorBrush();

  public SettingsWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    defColor.Color = Colors.Black;
    //defColor.Color = Colors.Black;  label1.Foreground = defColor;
  }

  private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
   defColor.Color = Colors.Black;
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186344/style-to-choose-suitable-foreground-according-to-background-color

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error messages?

Comment: no error message just does not color get updated may be INotifier :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the SettingsWindow DataContext = this; then the SettingsWindow class MUST implement INotifyPropertyChanged. to get the {Binding defColor} to work. Code you need:

```
public class SettingsWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public SettingsWindow()
    {
        // We are acting as our own 'ViewModel'
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Color _defColor;
    public Color defColor
    {
        get { return _defColor; }
        set
        {
            if (_defColor != value)
            {
                _defColor = value;
                if(null != PropertyChanged)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, "defColor");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As for targeting all labels in your application, the correct approach is to use Style, as previously suggested.
You will have to apply this style to each Label. Omit the x:Key to make it default style for your Labels

```
    <Style x:Key="LabelForeGroundStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding defColor}" />
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just from looking at the C# code you posted, I think your first problem is that you've done this

```
SolidColorBrush defColor = new SolidColorBrush();
```

instead of this

```
public SolidColoRBrush defColor { get; set; }
```

You can only bind to properties.

Your constructor will now look like this

```
public SettingsWindow()  
{  
    InitializeComponent();  
    defColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    this.DataContext = this;  // need to tell your window where to look for binding targets
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Binding each label to the same property, I think you should use [style](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/GuidedTourWPF_5.aspx), and apply this style for each label, e.g. with your binding:

```
  <Style x:Key="LabelForeGroundStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding defColor}" />
  </Style>
```

or even better, with [trigger](http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/FMoreno/archive/2008/10/01/414.aspx):

```
<Style.Triggers>
 <Trigger>
   <Trigger Property="Background" Value="Blue">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
   </Trigger>
 </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```